# How to convert the coordinates of one SpriteNode to another that is not a child or descendant

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, coordinates, nodes, touchesmoved

**In my SpriteKit Scene I got the following setup:**

Several nodes with the name `sourceNode` are direct children of the scene.
A node called `targetNode` is a child of another node called `sectionNode`, `sectionNode` is a child of the `scene` as well.

*`self` -->  `sourceNode`*

*`self` --> `sectionNode` --> `targetNode`*

When using the `touchesMoved` method to move the `sourceNode` I set the `position` of the `sourceNode` to the current location of the touch. Once the touch location is above the `targetNode` I want to snap the `sourceNode` to the `targetNode` by matching their positions.

**My issue:**

I do not seem to be able to properly convert in between the two coordinate spaces. I tried different variations of `convert(_:from:)` and `convert(_:to:)`, but none of it works. I know `convert` expects both nodes to be in the same node tree, but as both of them are descendants of the scene, aren't they considered part of the same node tree?

(If both `sourceNode` and `targetNode` are in the same coordinate system as siblings, the code works by just assigning the position of the `targetNode` to the position of the `sourceNode`)

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNodes = nodes(at: touchLocation)

        guard let sourceNode = touchedNodes.filter({$0.name == "sourceNode"}).first else { return }

        if let targetNode = touchedNodes.filter({$0.name == "targetNode"}).first {
            
            // sourceNode.position = targetNode.position    <-- works if both have the same parents   

            sourceNode.position = convert(targetNode.position, to: sourceNode)
        } else {
            sourceNode.position = touchLocation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you move source to your target, could you not do something like: sourceNode.removeFromParent(), sectionNode.addChild(sourceNode), sourceNode.position = targetNode.position, sourceNode.removeFromParent, addChild(sourceNode)

Comment: Simplified (too late to edit the above):sourceNode.move(toParent: sectionNode), sourceNode.position = targetNode.position, sourceNode.move(toParent: scene)

Comment: In my case that actually works pretty well! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. I'd still know a way to convert the coordinate spaces for other use cases though. I'm curious how this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move/snap the sourceNode to the coordinates of the targetNode, you could do the following:

```
sourceNode.move(toParent: sectionNode)
sourceNode.position = targetNode.position
sourceNode.move(toParent: scene)
```